# pushing object to stack

Tags: java, stack

I'm having a problem with my stack. I'm trying to implement backtracking to solve peg solitaire puzzle. I cannot push may object properly to the stack. When use `pop()` it always return the same object. I tried creating a simple java application and here's my code:

```
Try s = new Try();
Integer x;

s.x=0;
mark.push(s);
s.x=1;
mark.push(s);
s.x=2;
mark.push(s);

while(!mark.isEmpty()){
    s= (Try) mark.pop();
    x = s.x;
    System.out.println(x.toString());
}
```

`Try` only contains a public `Integer` variable.
It shows:
2
2
2

instead of
2
1
0

Comment: Why are you converting the return value of `pop` to `Try`, which is a bad name for what it is :D

Comment: Am I? I didn't noticed it. Just being desperate looking for the right answer.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `java.util.Stack<E>`, which has a generic type. You don't need that cast to `Try` if you just declare `mark` as a `Stack<Try>`. Also, I'm pretty sure `Stack` has its own `empty()` method for a reason (more efficient or something), which can be used in place of `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been noted, you are pushing one instance of `Try` three times, but here is a simpler scenario to demonstrate this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Test test = new Test();
    test.x = 1;
    list.add(test);
    test.x = 2;
    list.add(test);
    test.x = 3;
    list.add(test);
    System.out.println(list.stream().map(c -> new Pair<>(c.x, c == test)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private static class Test {
    int x;
}
```

This outputs `[3=true, 3=true, 3=true]` - they are all the same object and therefore have the same value.

Pushing (or adding in my example) an object just passes a reference to that object. You also have a reference to the object; modifying either will change both. If you want to fix this, create new instances of `Try` each time.

Comment: I about it, but is there any other way to get the target result without instantiating `Try` each time??

Comment: @user3619276 No, there isn't.

Comment: How about pushing Integer instead of `Try`, it gives me the result I want but there is only one instance of an `Integer` s.. 
It's awful if there's no other way.. Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you have just one instance of Try class placed in the stack 3 times. So the last value (2) is shown.

Create a different instance of Try for each push()

Comment: is there any other way of getting the target output without instantiating 3 `Try`?

Comment: @user3619276 If you want to use `Try`s for this, you need 3 of them. There is no alternative other than rewriting your code.